# Is there a good manual for the Windows Performance tool?

Tags: windows-xp, performance

**Is there a good manual for the Windows Performance tool?**

I want to find something I can read to describe what the data means that it is collecting.

I have output from Perfmon that shows that I have a process using more then 100% of the CPU.  I don't know how that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chapter or two in the Windows Resource Kit that covers performance monitor that I've always found helpful.  In addition, the blog of the performance team has been a good resource.  The blog address is: http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/ and you can find more information about the resource kit at http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Books/10345.aspx  (Even though this is a server reource kit, much of the information will still apply)

In particular, I believe what you are seeing is that %Process Time counter under the **Process** object shows a *SUM* of all CPUs on the machine, which can result in values over 100%.  The %Process Time counter under the **Proccesor** object shows the *AVE* across all CPUs.

Thanks,
Mark